# Jupyter Notebook is showing "Connecting to kernel" and found the below error message in Jupyter prompt window

Tags: jupyter-notebook

```
[W 01:27:37.384 NotebookApp] Terminals not available (error was No module named 'notebook.terminal')
[I 01:27:37.528 NotebookApp] JupyterLab extension loaded from C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site- 
packages\jupyterlab
[I 01:27:37.536 NotebookApp] JupyterLab application directory is 
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\share\jupyter\lab
[I 01:27:37.594 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: C:\Users\Arfeen Zia
[I 01:27:37.594 NotebookApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at:
[I 01:27:37.594 NotebookApp] http://localhost:8888/? token=485e227c30220e9df87579aa086673e5214e276e77bf7f4a
[I 01:27:37.595 NotebookApp]  or http://127.0.0.1:8888/ 
token=485e227c30220e9df87579aa086673e5214e276e77bf7f4a
[I 01:27:37.595 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to 
skip confirmation).
[C 01:27:40.171 NotebookApp]

To access the notebook, open this file in a browser:
    file:///C:/Users/Arfeen%20Zia/AppData/Roaming/jupyter/runtime/nbserver-16732-open.html
Or copy and paste one of these URLs:
    http://localhost:8888/?token=485e227c30220e9df87579aa086673e5214e276e77bf7f4a
 or http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=485e227c30220e9df87579aa086673e5214e276e77bf7f4a
[W 01:28:53.081 NotebookApp] Notebook Credit Risk Analytics -V2-checkpoint.ipynb is not trusted
[I 01:28:55.293 NotebookApp] Kernel started: f9f88f54-4a57-4934-8628-abed0616cc94
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
"__main__", mod_spec)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
exec(code, run_globals)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py", line 15, in <module>
from ipykernel import kernelapp as app
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
from .connect import *
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\connect.py", line 13, in <module>
from IPython.core.profiledir import ProfileDir
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\__init__.py", line 56, in <module>
from .terminal.embed import embed
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'IPython.terminal'
[I 01:28:58.288 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (1/5), new random ports
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
"__main__", mod_spec)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
exec(code, run_globals)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py", line 15, in <module>
from ipykernel import kernelapp as app
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
from .connect import *
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\connect.py", line 13, in <module>
from IPython.core.profiledir import ProfileDir
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\__init__.py", line 56, in <module>
from .terminal.embed import embed
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'IPython.terminal'
[W 01:29:26.482 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restart failed
[W 01:29:26.483 NotebookApp] Kernel d5d1858a-e4f3-4657-af40-74eb7b8fe24f died, removing from map.
[W 01:29:55.383 NotebookApp] Timeout waiting for kernel_info reply from f9f88f54-4a57-4934-8628- 
abed0616cc94
[E 01:29:55.385 NotebookApp] Error opening stream: HTTP 404: Not Found (Kernel does not exist: 
f9f88f54-4a57-4934-8628-abed0616cc94)
[W 01:30:11.499 NotebookApp] Timeout waiting for kernel_info reply from d5d1858a-e4f3-4657-af40- 
74eb7b8fe24f
[E 01:30:11.502 NotebookApp] Error opening stream: HTTP 404: Not Found (Kernel does not exist: 
d5d1858a-e4f3-4657-af40-74eb7b8fe24f)
[W 01:30:13.344 NotebookApp] 404 GET /api/kernels/d5d1858a-e4f3-4657-af40-74eb7b8fe24f/channels? 
session_id=ec7e0c095d2c4f718961a2112eafd9a9 (::1): Kernel does not exist: d5d1858a-e4f3-4657-af40- 
74eb7b8fe24f
[W 01:30:13.359 NotebookApp] 404 GET /api/kernels/d5d1858a-e4f3-4657-af40-74eb7b8fe24f/channels? 
session_id=ec7e0c095d2c4f718961a2112eafd9a9 (::1) 15.53ms referer=None
[W 01:30:16.348 NotebookApp] Replacing stale connection: d5d1858a-e4f3-4657-af40- 
74eb7b8fe24f:ec7e0c095d2c4f718961a2112eafd9a9
```